# Applescript handler, repeat with i from 1 to the number of this_list

Tags: applescript, handler

If someone could tell me what I am doing wrong here, or point me in the right direction to find the answer I would be grateful.

I have a list of numbers, and a list of corresponding names

```
numList {"1", "2", "4", "6"}
nameList {"bob", "joel", "mickey", "tara", "jason", "stacey"}
```

I am trying to make a handler to take the numbers from numList and get the corresponding names as a list.

```
The result should be {"bob", "joel", "tara", "stacey"
```

this is what I have, but it does not return the correct names.

```
on myFirstHandler(this_list, other_list)
    set rest_list to {}
    set availlist to {}
    repeat with h from 1 to the number of this_list
        set the rest_list to item h of other_list
        set the end of the availlist to rest_list
    end repeat
    return availlist
end myFirstHandler

set numList {"1", "2", "4", "6"}
set nameList {"bob", "joel", "mickey", "tara", "jason", "stacey"}

myFirstHandler(numList, nameList)
set AlcoholAvailable to the result

returns {"bob", "joel", "mickey", "tara"}
```

Comment: I need to commend you for writing an excellent question: you stated your problem, what you expected the result to be, what result you got, and the code you used to get that result.  Well done.  It makes helping that much easier and more pleasant to do.  +1 for you.

Comment: Oh, goodness, thank you for the wonderful compliment and all of your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were very, very close with your attempt.  Here's a modified, corrected version of it:

```
on myFirstHandler(this_list, other_list)
    set rest_list to {}

    repeat with h in this_list
        set the end of rest_list to item h of other_list
    end repeat

    return rest_list
end myFirstHandler


set numList to {1, 2, 4, 6}
set nameList to {"bob", "joel", "mickey", "tara", "jason", "stacey"}

myFirstHandler(numList, nameList)
set AlcoholAvailable to the result
```

The main key difference is the way the `repeat` loop is defined: in your original attempt, you were looping through the ***indices*** of the source list, so you were always going to be utilising numbers that run `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6`, and therefore, extracting those items from your target list.  In my modified version, I'm looping through the ***values***, therefore I'm able to make use of the numbers from the source list `1, 2, 4, 6`.

So compare your `repeat` clause:

```
repeat with h from 1 to the number of this_list
```

with mine:

```
repeat with h in this_list
```

Both are perfectly valid bits of AppleScript, but do slightly different things: one uses **indices**, the other uses **values**.

---

A slightly more advanced, but ever so more versatile, method of doing it would be like this:

```
set numList to {1, 2, 4, 6}
set nameList to {"bob", "joel", "mickey", "tara", "jason", "stacey"}

on map(L, function)
    local L, function

    tell result to repeat with x in L
        set x's contents to function's fn(x)
    end repeat

    L
end map

on itemInList(L)
    script
        on fn(x)
            item x of L
        end fn
    end script
end itemInList

map(numList, itemInList(nameList))
```

Here, I've defined a "basic" *mapping* function.  A `mapping` function takes a function—in this case, one that returns an element from a target list—and applies that function to each element from an array—in this case, your source list, `numList`.  This list is modified in the process, so you'll find that the elements of `numList` have been replaced with `{"bob", "joel", "tara", "stacey"}`.

What makes this construct special is that you can replace the function (handler) that `map` uses in this example, `itemInList()` and define other handlers of a similar nature that do other things to your list.

Comment: Yes, the different of using values is exactly what I needed here. Thank you, again, so much!